# Prevent page break within footnote in ConTeXt

Tags: footnotes, context

I have the following example of footenotes:

```
\definepapersize[MyBook][A5]
\setuppapersize[MyBook][A5]

\usetypescript[times]
\setupbodyfont[times,11pt]
\setupbodyfontenvironment   [default][em=italic] % use italic as em, not slanted

\setuplayout[location=middle,
  topspace=1cm,
  bottomspace=1.5cm,
  width=middle,
  cutspace=1.4cm,
  backspace=2.5cm,
  height=fit,
  footer=1.2cm,
  grid=yes]

\starttext

\section{Geist}

In den vorausgegangenen Diskussionen haben wir festgestellt, dass der Mensch aus zwei Dimensionen besteht, einer materiellen und einer spirituellen Dimension. Die verschiedenen Ansichten über den Geist werden allgemein in vier Gruppen unterteilt:

\startitemize[n,fit][start=1,stopper={.\space},margin=1em]
\item Einige streiten die Existenz des Geistes gänzlich ab, akzeptieren die Existenz immateriellen Seins nicht und begegnen behaupteten spirituellen Phänomenen mit materiellen Erklärungen.\footnote{Typische Vertreter: Demokrit, Zenon von Elea, Thomas Hobbes, die Behavioristen, Jalaf, As-Ari, Baqillani, Abu Bark Assam}
\item Einer anderen Ansicht zufolge gibt es zwar spirituelle Phänomene, erkennt jedoch keine Begründung für den Geist als eigenes Wesen. Deren Vertreter unterscheiden zwischen spirituellen und materiellen Angelegenheiten, betrachten die spirituellen Angelegenheiten jedoch als materiellen und physiologischen Vorgängen entsprungen.\footnote{Typische Vertreter: Thomas Henry Huxley}
\item Eine dritte Sichtweise erkennt Geist und Körper als zwei voneinander unabhängige Elemente an, die jedoch einen materiellen Ursprung teilen.\footnote{Typische Vertreter: William James, Betrand Russel}
\item Eine weitere Auffassung zufolge beeinflussen sich Geist und Körper wechselseitig und außer an eine körperliche, materielle Dimension wird auch eine eigene spirituelle Dimension akzeptiert, der alle spirituellen Phänomene zuzuteilen sind.\footnote{Die meisten muslimischen Philosophen und Wissenschaftler vertreten diese Auffassung.}
\stopitemize
\blank[line]

\stoptext
```

The Problem is: The last footnote conflicts in the text and the footer - so that ConTeXt makes a page breaking footenote, lacking of a good rule to handle this situation. I do not know, what to do best to fix this. Are there any possibilities without changing the footnotes and the text itself?

Comment: This is a complete minimal example that is sufficient to demonstrate your problem: `\starttext \dorecurse{4}{\input knuth}\par \footnote{\dorecurse{10}{thisisaverylongword }} \stoptext`

Comment: Correct, of course much better than mine, I need experience in this. Thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I understand you don't want the footnote to break at a hyphen. You can suppress the hyphenation with

```
\setupnote
    [footnote]
    [align=nothyphenated]
```

To not break the individual footnotes at all, put them into a box:

```
\setupnotation
    [footnote]
    [before=\vbox\bgroup,after=\egroup]
```

Comment: No, that is not my problem. I do not want a footnote breaking at all (all my footnotes are less than a half page, so it should be possible in general). 

[And apart from that: `\setupnote
    [footnote]
    [align=nothyphenated]` does break the footnote AFTER the word, which was broken at a hyphen before, but it should be before this word. ]